# MySQL Connection through ASP.NET

Tags: mysql, asp.net, textbox, connection

How do I solve this?
I'm trying to figure out how to pass my mysql data into a textbox.
Also, I'm having an error when i run my program (Connection must be valid and open).

```
try
    {
        string sCon = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=pac;UID=root";
        String s = "select * from pac.pac_excel where employeenumber=" + this.employeenumber_txt.Text + ";";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(sCon);
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(s, con);
        MySqlDataAdapter dat = new MySqlDataAdapter(s, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dat.Fill(ds, "pac");

        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(s);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                status_txt.Text = myReader["status"].ToString();
            }
            myReader.Close();
            con.Close();

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: what errormessage do you get when running this?

Comment: The program is running. The error says "Connection must be valid and open". It is supposed to be the variable of mysql.

Comment: As gkrisky says you should probably move your connection open() to before your dat.Fill() call. Give him the credit if this works for you :)

Comment: thanks, but it still says Connection must be valid and open.

Answer (score 0):

Change your sCon like this,

```
string sCon = "Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=pac;Integrated Security=True;UID=root";
```

If you using Sql Express edition, you need to add \SQLEXPRESS otherwise no need of this.And Change your con.Open() to the line below of con declaration.

Comment: thank you, but it still says the same error after moving the con.Open() after declaring con.